# Can I reverse the stream direction of my terminal?

Tags: bash, terminal, cmd.exe

I'm not sure on how to word this question any other way but that's it. 
Is it possible to reverse the way your terminal prints text?

For example if I type a command, I type it from the bottom of the terminal and the output will be produced from the bottom. I want to know if I can reverse this so I input from the top and my output is from the top.

Comment: Are you looking for a completely "reversed" terminal (bottom-up instead of top-down) or for a simple "input line is always at the bottom, results are displayed above it"?

Comment: Either would be great, Ideally I am looking for the completely reversed way but the second way you mentioned is also good I think.

Comment: Here are related questions on other sites: [Reverse bash console text flow](http://serverfault.com/questions/152310/reverse-bash-console-text-flow) [Pushdown Terminal Output](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/35627/pushdown-terminal-outputhttp://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/35627/pushdown-terminal-output) [How do you reverse terminal command line to the top?](http://www.unix.com/unix-desktop-dummies-questions-answers/145379-how-do-you-reverse-terminal-command-line-top.html)

Answer (score 3):

I got a rough approximation to your desired behaviour by:

```
(while read line;do tput home;tput ri;echo "$line";done;tput home;tput ri)< <(ls -l)
```

So you could make a shell script and put every command through that, I guess. I kind of like it - only you can't scroll down once it goes off the bottom of the screen! Maybe there's a way around that.

read `man terminfo` for lots of info on messing with your terminal.